# Elastic search nested function scores and script scoring with function score

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement a custom score based on how important a field is.

However I need to compare across multiple indices of different document types. These documents have different fields with different importances.
I need the scores from these results to be comparable and therefore want to ignore TF/IDF and score normalisation.

So if a search query matches 2 important fields and 1 less important field it's score should be twice the important score plus the less important score:

> (8* (1+1)) + (3*(1)) = 19

**The result I am getting is a score of 11**. As the query below seems to ignore the inner function score and computes:

> (8*1) + (3*1).

The score explanation is also below which seems to show it's ignoring the inner function_score and just giving it a constant score of 1(this is what I want to stop happening).

I have tried not nesting function scores and using simple should queries as well as trying **boost_factor** instead of 'weight' and giving matched fields a constant score all of which have the same outcome.

Also rather than applying a constant weight to multiply by I'd like to use a script_score to compute the outer result. However the '_score' that gets passed up is not the score that I have just computed but the original search score.
Is there a field I can use other than '_score' within a script_score to get this?

Thanks in advance!

### Query

```
"query": {
 "function_score": {
  "functions": [
    {
      "weight": 8.0,
      "filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "function_score": {
              "functions": [
                {
                  "weight": 1.0,
                  "filter": {
                    "fquery": {
                      "query": {
                        "query_string": {
                          "query": "match*",
                          "fields": [
                            "ImportantField1"
                          ],
                          "default_operator": "and",
                          "analyzer": "english",
                          "analyze_wildcard": true
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "weight": 1.0,
                  "filter": {
                    "fquery": {
                      "query": {
                        "query_string": {
                          "query": "match*",
                          "fields": [
                            "ImportantField2"
                          ],
                          "default_operator": "and",
                          "analyzer": "english",
                          "analyze_wildcard": true
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  } // More field queries that don't match omitted for clarity
                }
              ],
              "score_mode": "sum",
              "boost_mode": "replace"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "weight": 3.0,
      "filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "function_score": {
              "functions": [
                {
                  "weight": 1.0,
                  "filter": {
                    "fquery": {
                      "query": {
                        "query_string": {
                          "query": "match*",
                          "fields": [
                            "LessImportantField"
                          ],
                          "default_operator": "and",
                          "analyzer": "english",
                          "analyze_wildcard": true
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }// More field queries that don't match omitted for clarity

              ],
              "query": {
                "match_all": {}
              },
              "score_mode": "sum",
              "boost_mode": "replace"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
     "match_all": {} // Filtering done here, omitted for clarity
    }
  },
  "score_mode": "sum",
  "boost_mode": "replace"
 }
}
```

## Score Explanation

```
"_explanation": {
           "value": 11,
           "description": "function score, product of:",
           "details": [
              {
                 "value": 11,
                 "description": "Math.min of",
                 "details": [
                    {
                       "value": 11,
                       "description": "function score, score mode [sum]",
                       "details": [
                          {
                             "value": 8,
                             "description": "function score, product of:",
                             "details": [
                                {
                                   "value": 1,
                                   "description": "match filter: QueryWrapperFilter(function score (ConstantScore(*:*), functions: [{filter(QueryWrapperFilter(ImportantField1:match*)), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.WeightFactorFunction@64b3fd0e]}{filter(QueryWrapperFilter(ImportantField2:match*)), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.WeightFactorFunction@38ed4b5c]}]))"
                                },
                                {
                                   "value": 8,
                                   "description": "product of:",
                                   "details": [
                                      {
                                         "value": 1,
                                         "description": "constant score 1.0 - no function provided"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "value": 8,
                                         "description": "weight"
                                      }
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          },
                          {
                             "value": 3,
                             "description": "function score, product of:",
                             "details": [
                                {
                                   "value": 1,
                                   "description": "match filter: QueryWrapperFilter(function score (ConstantScore(*:*), functions: [{filter(QueryWrapperFilter(LessImportantField:match*)), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.WeightFactorFunction@3ce99ebf]}]))"
                                },
                                {
                                   "value": 3,
                                   "description": "product of:",
                                   "details": [
                                      {
                                         "value": 1,
                                         "description": "constant score 1.0 - no function provided"
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "value": 3,
                                         "description": "weight"
                                      }
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          }
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "value": 3.4028235e+38,
                       "description": "maxBoost"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "value": 1,
                 "description": "queryBoost"
              }
           ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this isn't possible. Function_score only takes filters within its functions to apply scores. This means that they either match or don't hence scores from a nested function_score cannot be passed up.

I did manage to disable query normalisation using:

```
"similarity": {
           "default": {
              "queryNorm": "1",
              "type": //whatever type you want
              }
            }
```

However this meant that TF/IDF became a problem for me as it these values were different for each of my indices so I ended up using writing a custom similarity class and setting these values to just be a constant of 1.